# Are R packages (and their dependencies) OS specific?

Tags: r, package

On Mac OS X, loading `data.table.` did not require `chron`. On Windows, it was required.

- Is there something wrong with either the Mac or the Windows version?
- If not, how could I detect these OS specific differences prior to trying to load `data.table` (or similar)?

  Output on MAC:

  > require(data.table, lib.loc='packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1')
  >   sessionInfo()
  >   R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
  >   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

  locale:
  [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

  attached base packages:
  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods
  [7] base

  other attached packages:
  [1] data.table_1.9.2

  loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.3   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2
  [5] tools_3.1.

Other files in the library folder:

```
list.dirs('packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1', full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
 [1] "colorspace"   "data.table"   "dichromat"    "digest"      
 [5] "ggplot2"      "gtable"       "labeling"     "manipulate"  
 [9] "MASS"         "munsell"      "packrat"      "plyr"        
[13] "proto"        "RColorBrewer" "Rcpp"         "reshape"     
[17] "reshape2"     "rstudio"      "scales"       "stringr"     
[21] "yaml"
```

Standard R library folder:

```
list.dirs('/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/library', full.names=FALSE, recursive=FALSE)
 [1] "base"      "compiler"  "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices"
 [6] "grid"      "lattice"   "MASS"      "Matrix"    "methods"  
[11] "nlme"      "parallel"  "splines"   "stats"     "stats4"   
[16] "tcltk"     "tools"     "utils"
```

Comment: No.  The imports are clearly defined at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html as `Imports: methods, chron, reshape2`. On your Mac machine you probably already had `chron` installed.

Comment: I added the contents of my library folders. No `chron` anywhere.

Comment: What's your `R` version? At least w/ my 3.1.2 and `data.table 1.9.2` , `chron` is only a "suggests," so it doesn't have to be there to load `data.table` .

Comment: You're probably installing different versions of `data.table`.  The most recent CRAN version is `1.9.4`.